# Syncs Slicers or a slicer for multiple query in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Anyone have a work around for a slicer that would work on multiple queries (at least 2).

I noticed that when I use a different query, the pivot table I made won't appear on the slicers Report Connections.

I tried doing a merge with both tables (The relationship is 1 to many) and for some reason Right or Full Outer doesn't work right. (I have 50 entries on table 1 and table 2 has 4000 entries but when I try doing full or right, it will only result to 40 entries)

I tried doing the Data Model but it doesn't work on my end. I notice the examples using it are not Queries so that  might be the reason why it is not working.

Comment: I assume you are talking about having a linked Slicer between two pivot tables (using PQ as a data source)? I'm not an expert on this stuff, but I can make this work using queries loaded to the data model. I did either need to use the field from ONE of the data sources of as the row/column aggregate for both pivot tables, or link both of them to a single master table for that field and use that (because my data sample was many to many I couldn't link the tables directly, idk if that would make it work for yours since you say yours is one to many).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying, I actually tried doing that by adding the data model of both query tables but for some reason it doesn't work properly. I might have done something wrong while doing it, will do a retest later when I have time.